# How do boundaries change in this particular double integral?

Tags: integration

Is there a simpler representation for an integral of the form $$\int_1^x \int_1^t f(u)\; du\; dt$$ analogous to $$\sum_{t=1}^x \sum_{u=1}^t f(u)=\sum_{t=1}^x (x-t+1)f(t)$$ ? It seems like there should be, but I haven't been able to come up with an analogous formula or find one online.

Comment: I have changed the title, see if you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fubini's theorem to integrate in $t$ first. In [Iverson's bracket notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), you get 
$$
\begin{split}
\int_1^x\int_1^t f(u)\,du dt&= \int\int\,f(u)\,[1\le u\le t]\cdot[1\le t\le x]\,dudt \\
&=\int f(u)\left(\int\underbrace{[1\le u\le t][1\le t\le x]}_{=[1\le u\le t\le x]}\, dt \right)\, du\\ 
&=\int f(u)(x-u)[1\le u \le x]\, du \\
&=\int_1^x f(u)(x-u)\,du.
\end{split}$$